# Method Override with some condition in Console application

Tags: c#, .net, overriding

I am creating one console application. I have one class in which I wrote some methods. Now I want to override some methods of that class in a different class. But this should be override only if condition satisfied.

For example,

```
public partial Class MainClass
{
   public string GetPath()
   {
      string temp =  Method1();
      return temp;
   }

    protected virtual string Method1()
    {
       //logic
    }


}
```

If some condition satisfied then only overridden method should be called

```
public partial class ChildClass : MainCLass
{
    public override void Method1()
    {
        //MY Logic
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this? Is it possible to do so?

Comment: You could just conditionally call base.Method1() or something (I confuse these calls across languages). But the point is that if you need to do that, then your OOP is wrong. Maybe you shouldn't do an override, but regular functions, and use polymorphism to your advantage, cast the object to either of the types depending on what method you want called.

Comment: +1 for @AlexanderMP comment. 
I removed console-application" tag, since this is not related at all with your current problem (it would be the same in a desktop or web application)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `ChildClass` you can do something like this:

```
public partial class ChildClass : MainCLass
{
    public override void Method1()
    {
        if(condition)
        {
            base.Method1();

            return;
        }

        //YOUR LOGIC
    }
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
public class A
    {
        public virtual void MethodA()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A:MethodA");
        }
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        public bool CallBase { get; set; }

        public B()
        {
            CallBase = false;
        }

        public override void MethodA()
        {
            if (CallBase)
            {
                base.MethodA();

                return;;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("B:MethodA");
        }
    }

    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        a.MethodA();
        b.MethodA();

        b.CallBase = true;

        b.MethodA();

        A c = new B();

        c.MethodA();

        A d = new B(true);

        d.MethodA();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Output

> A:MethodA
>   B:MethodA
>   A:MethodA
>   B:MethodA
>   A:MethodA

Comment: you can't return `void`; so `base.Method1(); return;` is the right syntax

Comment: @Karol: I've added `return` required to your implemenation

Comment: @Karol: when I call Method1(), it directly call my main method instead of overridden. Why so?

Comment: @Karol: Actually I am calling overridden method from my first class' method. For example Method C is exist within  class A and I am calling overridden method from this Method C.

Comment: @Ankita you can call overloaded method only from child class, in base class you can't call children methods.